# How to find the available POSIX system calls api list for my Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, system-calls

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 and I need to use those functions

```
int spawnv(   mode, path, argv );
int spawnve(  mode, path, argv, envp );
int spawnvp(  mode, file, argv );
int spawnvpe( mode, file, argv, envp );
```

I know that they are compiler dependent, so how to find system calls supported by my compiler/system? or how to find my multi-tasking api for processes system calls?

I tried using man spawn + clicking on tab but nothing appears.

Comment: Those functions are none of them POSIX functions — so it isn't clear what you're after.  POSIX has [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and a swarm of relatives, all starting `posix_spawn…` (see the 'SEE ALSO' section for other links).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay but where to find the document or the command which contain the api of functions and system calls I can use? I tried man posix_sp + tab and nothing appears in my command terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page on [Spawn (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(computing)) indicates that the `spawn*()` functions you reference are from DOS/Windows.  They don't have direct analogues in Unix — although they were originally derived from Unix (`fork()` and `exec*()`) and adapted to DOS/Windows.

There are no direct analogues to those functions in POSIX.  Arguably the nearest approach is [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) and its multitude of support functions (see the 'SEE ALSO' section on that page for links to the other functions).

I didn't find any similar functions in Linux, even when looking at:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2
- https://linux.die.net/man/2
- https://linux.die.net/man/3

Similar functionality can probably be written using `fork()` (sometimes), `exec*()` and `waitpid()` or one of its relatives (sometimes), but it might not be as easy as all that.  It depends in part on how exact and complete the emulation functionality has to be.